# How to load axspreadsheet in Visual Studio 2005 or C# Express 2008

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, winforms-interop

I have office 2007 installed with .NET programmability checked.
From VS2005/VC#2008 Toolbox I tried to add a new item, the axSpreadsheet control, unfortunately I could not find it from .NET Framework / COM reference.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? My main purpose is to load xls file to winform.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a excel work book to your windows form by using the AxSpreadsheet control. To use this control you need to add a reference of AxInterop.OWC11.dll and Interop.Office.DLL.

http://dotnetcodelearner.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/displaying-the-excel-workbook-in-windows-form-using-axspreadsheet/